# Average objects in an arraylist

Tags: java

I have a program where the user inputs a stock object into an arraylist.  A stock object is made of a stock symbol, number of shares, and cost per share.  As long as the user keeps choosing the first option, they are prompted to add stock objects to a growing arraylist.  I want it so that when the user inputs 2, I want the LIFO average price of the last 250 objects entered to be displayed.  How can I display the average cost of an arraylist of objects?  For example, if the user input

```
AAPL 200 15
```

and

```
AAPL 300 20
```

, now they have bought `200` shares at `15` each and `300` more at `20` each, but I only want the average of the first `250`.  Here is my code:

```
package stocks;
import java.util.*;


public class Stocks {
    private String sym;
    private List<Purchase> purchases;

    public Stocks(final String symbol) {
        this.sym = symbol;
        purchases = new ArrayList<Purchase>();
    }

    public void addPurchase(final int amt, final double cost){
        purchases.add(new Purchase(amt,cost));
    }

    public String getSym(){
        return sym;
    }

    public void setSym(){
        this.sym = sym;
    }

    public double getAvg250() {
        int i = 0;
        int total = 0;
        int shares = 0; 
        while (i < purchases.size()) {
            Purchase p = purchases.get(i);
            if (shares + p.getAmt() >= 250) {
                total += (250 - shares) * p.getCost();
                shares = 250;
                break;
            }
            shares += p.getAmt();
            i++; 
        }
        return total * 1.0 / shares;
    }


 class Purchase {
   private int amt;
   private int cost;

   public Purchase(int amt, double cost){

   }

    public int getAmt() {
    return amt;
}

public void setAmt(int amt) {
    this.amt = amt;
}

public int getCost() {
    return cost;
}

public void setCost(int cost) {
    this.cost = cost;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

       int choice = 0;

       while (choice == 0){
         System.out.println("Enter 1 to input a new stock, or 2 to query a stock's price, 3 to quit: ");
         Scanner sc1 = new Scanner (System.in);
         choice = sc1.nextInt();



         if(choice==1){
           ArrayList<Stocks> StocksList = new ArrayList<Stocks>();
           Scanner sc2 = new Scanner (System.in);
           System.out.println("Please enter the stock symbol: ");
           String sym = sc2.next();
           System.out.println("Please enter the number of shares: ");
           int amt = sc2.nextInt();
           System.out.println("Please enter the price per share: ");
           double cost = sc2.nextDouble();


           Map<String, Stocks> stocks = new HashMap<String, Stocks>();

           Stocks s = stocks.get(sym);
           if (s == null) {
               s = new Stocks(sym);
               stocks.put(sym, s);
           }
           s.addPurchase(amt, cost);
           StocksList.add(s);




           System.out.println(getAvg250());

         }
         choice = 0;

         if(choice==3){
           System.exit(0);
         }
       }
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Can your list have different kinds of stock, or just one?

Comment: It can have different kinds, and later on I'm going to add a search feature which will display the average cost of the stock the user searches for

Comment: Do you need to maintain the original cost for each entry of a stock ticker, or just a running average?

Comment: The average will be calculated when the user inputs 2, so the most recent 250 shares will be averaged.

Answer (score 0):

I would design the data structure slightly differently, if you want to be able to easily calculate the average for one stock symbol. You could keep a list of stock purchases for every stock symbol. The code would look something like this (fill in your getters/setters):

```
public class Stock {
    private String symbol;
    private List<Purchase> purchases;

    public Stock(final String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
        purchases = new ArrayList<Purchase>();
    }

    public void addPurchase(final int amt, final int cost) {
        purchases.add(new Purchase(amt, cost));
    }
}

public class Purchase {
   private int amt;
   private int cost;
}
```

This way you can calculate the average cost of the first 250 shares (max) like this:

```
public float getAvg250() {
    int i = 0;
    int total = 0;
    int shares = 0; 
    while (i < purchases.size()) {
        Purchase p = purchases.get(i);
        if (shares + p.getAmt() >= 250) {
            total += (250 - shares) * p.getCost();
            shares = 250;
            break;
        }
        shares += p.getAmt();
        i++; 
    }
    return total * 1.0 / shares;
}
```

Since you want to add a search feature, add all the `Stock` objects into a `HashMap` indexed by stock symbol for O(1) retrieval. This also helps when adding a purchase, because you will need to retrieve the corresponding `Stock` object to update the list of purchases:

```
Map<String, Stock> stocks = new HashMap<String, Stock>();
// Get input from the user 
//......
Stock s = stocks.get(sym);
if (s == null) {
    s = new Stock(sym);
    stocks.put(sym, s);
}
s.addPurchase(amt, cost);
```

Comment: Using this method can I input the objects into the list the same way?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the answer to include a skeleton of what that would like.

Comment: I've never used hashmap before so I'm trying to understand it.  Where is the <String, Stock> coming from in the hashmap declaration?

Comment: `Map` is a parametric type, just like list. It takes two type arguments, one each for key and value. For our case, the stock symbol (`String`) is the key and the `Stock` object is the value. You can read more about `Map` here - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Comment: I can only seem to add elements to the hashmap instead of the whole stock object

Comment: So, you'll need to create a new `Stock` object for each stock type, if one doesn't exist in your Map. I'll edit the answer to reflect this.

Comment: So am I creating a new ArrayList for each stock type?

Comment: Yes because you want to group the stock purchases by stock type. This makes it easier to calculate the average for one particular stock.

Comment: So I'm trying to put this together and for some reason now Eclipse is telling me there's something wrong with my main method, I edited my original post with the new code.